# Changing ajax function to modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I been trying to use bootstraps modal for my site. now i need to change this following code to work along with the modal

```
$(document.body).on('click','.socialIcon',null,function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('social_','');
    var win = function(resp) {
        var dialogWin = $('#socRegPopup');
        if(dialogWin.length){
            dialogWin.remove();
        }
        $('#wrapper').append(resp);  
        dialogWin = $('#socRegPopup');
        dialogWin.dialog({ 
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 515,
            modal: true,
            position: 'center',
            resizable: false
        });
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: liveSite +'/index2.php?obj=social&task=getSocialForm',
        type:'get',
        data: {programId: id},
        success:win});    
});
```

i Tried changing it to this to use bootstraps modal

```
$(document.body).on('click','.socialIcon',null,function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('social_','');
    var win = function(resp) { 
        $('#wrapper').append(resp);  
        $('#socRegPopup').modal();
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: liveSite +'/index2.php?obj=social&task=getSocialForm',
        type:'get',
        data: {programId: id},
        success:win});    
});
```

this one works but the promblem is that the data is not changing
for example there are 3 buttons when i click the button 1 it will output correct but the next all buttons will output button 1 data. any guide how to make modal to work on ajax

Answer (score 0):

This fix my problem. I don't know if this is a better solution

```
$(document.body).on('click','.socialIcon',null,function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('social_','');
    var win = function(resp) { 

        var element = document.getElementById("socRegPopup");
        if(element){
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
     } 

        $('#wrapper').append(resp);  
        $('#socRegPopup').modal();
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: liveSite +'/index2.php?obj=social&task=getSocialForm',
        type:'get',
        data: {programId: id},
        success:win});    
});
```